# Character Counter using Keyup and Keydown

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to add a Character counter to my website. Therefore I have a span with id="counter" and a input type="texture" with id="producttext". I started my Code with a :

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function test() {

var textEntered, a;

textEntered = document.getElementById('producttext').value;
a = document.getElementById('counter');

a.innerHTML = textEntered;


});
```

But the output is not the count of the character. It is the content
How to solve this ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: You should be using the `value` of the textarea, not the `textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```js
const counter = document.querySelector("#counter");
const textEl = document.querySelector("#foo");

textEl.addEventListener("input", () => {
  counter.textContent = textEl.value.length;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" />
<span id="counter">0</span>
```

Comment: then I get this error : TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'counter.textContent = textEntered.length')

Comment: I updated the answer with a snippet so you can compare. It seems your problem is that you are not finding the elements when using the selectors. Double check that the IDs match